# Clear QPainter drawings

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qimage

I'm looking at the Plug and Paint example for Qt and there isn't an option to create a new image or clear drawings. How would I erase everything I have drawn using QPainter?

The New image implementation I created simply sets the `QImage` to white and calls `update()`

```
void PaintArea::newFile()
{
    theImage.fill(qRgb(255, 255, 255));
    update();
    updateGeometry();
}
```

However, if I want to open an image and draw all over it and then clear the drawings, I don't want to erase the image I opened as well.

Comment: Are you looking for something like painter->eraseRect(0,0,500,500); ?

Comment: Are you meaning that you want something like layered drawings where you only erase the top layer?

Comment: @RobbieE Yes, something like that sounds about right.